# Is there any method to make ckedit read odf file directly?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, odf

I want to build an webOffice platform, which can read odf and save odf.
I found ckeditor is really good, however it save files in html, is there any way to let ckeditor read odf and edit odf file directly?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to create something that transforms odf <-> html